# Converting the vertical datum of elevation data in R

Tags: r, australia, vertical-transformation

I have elevation data for 699 points around Australia. I want to calculate the difference between these point elevations and the highest elevation within 25 nautical miles - in simple terms I want to get a sense of the terrain around each point.

I have been able to obtain the maximum elevation within a 25nm radius using the [SRTM-derived 3 Second Digital Elevation Models Version 1.0](https://ecat.ga.gov.au/geonetwork/srv/eng/catalog.search#/metadata/72760). However, this DEM uses EGM96 as the vertical datum, whereas my point data is with reference to "mean sea level" which I take to mean [AUSGeoid2020](https://www.ga.gov.au/scientific-topics/positioning-navigation/geodesy/ahdgm/ausgeoid2020).

In order to find the difference between the two elevations I need to transform one set of data to the vertical datum of the other; it would probably be easier to transform my point data to EGM96.

I have downloaded the AUSGeoid2020 ASCII file which, I believe, will permit me to transform the point elevations to the [Australian Height Datum (AHD)](https://www.ga.gov.au/scientific-topics/positioning-navigation/geodesy/ahdgm/ahd). Now I need to convert from AHD to EGM96...

I've transformed geospatial data between horizontal datums before - in R - but I haven't been able to locate any documentation relating to transforming vertical datums.

Comment: AUSGeoid2020 is only correct if your data is in GDA2020, you most probably want AUSGeoid09 if your data is in GDA94, the transformation grid is available from Geoscience Australia http://www.ga.gov.au/ausgeoid/ geoid height is higher than AHD so find your value and add it to your Z value of your points and you should be there; to do this you can express the AUSGeoid09 as a raster then use overlay to find the Z.

Comment: Absolutely fantastic @MichaelStimson! Can you please add this as an answer so I can mark it as answering the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AUSGeoid2020](https://www.ga.gov.au/scientific-topics/positioning-navigation/geodesy/ahdgm/ausgeoid2020) is only correct if your data is in [GDA2020](https://www.icsm.gov.au/datum/gda2020-fact-sheets), which is an emerging standard not fully implemented, you most probably want [AUSGeoid09](http://www.ga.gov.au/scientific-topics/positioning-navigation/geodesy/ahdgm/differences) if your data is in GDA94, the transformation grid is available from Geoscience Australia [ga.gov.au/ausgeoid](http://ga.gov.au/ausgeoid).

Geoid height is higher than AHD so find your value and add it to your Z value of your points and you should be there; to do this you can express the AUSGeoid09 as a raster then use overlay to find the Z.

If you're working in python you could use a tool like [Get Cell Value](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0017000000m8000000):

```
import os, sys, arcpy

PointLayer  = sys.argv[1] # Your point layer
RasterLayer = sys.argv[2] # your displacement raster

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(PointLayer,['SHAPE@XY','SHAPE@Z']) as UpCur:
    # iterate the rows
    for EachPoint in UpCur:
        # get the value from the raster at the given point as a float
        XY            = '{} {}'.format(EachPoint[0][0],EachPoint[0][1])
        RasterValue   = float(arcpy.GetCellValue_management(RasterLayer,XY).getOutput(0))
        EachPoint[1] += RasterValue # modify the Z by the raster value
        UpCur.updateRow(EachPoint)  # commit changes
```

Which doesn't require a Spatial Analyst or 3d Analyst license; if you have 3d Analyst you can use a tool like [Add Surface Information](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00q900000016000000) to sample the raster for each point.